# Studying inflation on my groceries, how to correctly show the increase of prices?

Tags: time-series

I have price data from the last two years from my online groceries purchases on an online supermarket for all the products I bought. I want to study the increase of prices for the products that I usually buy; since I didn't always buy the same products, I am taking an average of a six months period for all the products that I take into account, so my data is resampled with a period of six months.
Now I am facing the problem that I don't know what is a correct way to show inflation/price change:

1. Absolute differences don't tell much since the same absolute increase for different starting prices has a different impact
2. Relative or percentage price increases are more suitable, however, what's a good way to show the increase of prices? If I am considering periods of six months, I could show the increase w.r.t. the previous period, but this can be misleading. For instance, if a 1\$ product increases 20%, the new price is 1.20\$, but if it now deceases 20% it will have a price of 0.96\$, so if I use relative increases I will see +20%, then -20%, which might lead to think that the price is the same as in the beginning, but that's not the case
3. I could use the increase w.r.t. the original price, but not always the first price was the lowest. For some products, I noticed that their price went down on 2021 w.r.t. 2020 and up again in 2022.

What would be a good way to show how prices changed in the last two years?

Comment: This is usually done by constructing an artificial "basket" of products and comparing its costs over time.  Then all you have to do is report the cost of that basket in each year.

Comment: @whuber hmm, that's a very good suggestion. I guess it would also work considering categories of groceries (diary, meat, cleaning, etc)?

Comment: Sure: you can define any group of products or services you like and track their total cost over time.  That underlies the concepts of "core inflation," "headline inflation," and various forms of price indexes like CPIs and PPIs (producer price indexes).  The US government publishes tables of thousands of PPIs to keep track of changes in costs within specialized industries, for instance.